# Android: Adding additional options when users presses and holds an shortcut Icon in the homescreen

Tags: android

When users presses and holds any App shortcut Icon in a home screen, "remove" and "edit" options appear at the top of the screen so that users can drop them in those options.

I would like to add an extra option at the top when users presses and holds any Icon on home screen or any widget for that matter.

Is it possible to be done by an Android Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For one, there isn't a single standard "home screen" implementation. If you wanted to write home screen replacement with more options, you could.

Answer (score 0):

This question has a new answer these days. This can now be accomplished in Android 7.1+ using App Shortcuts.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html